# "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement commentjson" when DIYing Alexa on raspberry pi 3 B+

Tags: python, json

Hello and cheers for your time.

I am trying to implement Alexa Voice Server on a *Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+*, following this official tutorial:

https://developer.amazon.com/docs/alexa-voice-service/set-up-raspberry-pi.html

It seems to be very straightforward, and the Pi is brand new and running the most recent version of NOOBS. However, on the first step of the 'Build the AVS Device SDK', where I have to run

```
cd /home/pi/
sudo bash setup.sh config.json [-s 1234]
```

It produces the error on the title. I have included a picture (sorry in advance that it is not a screenshot) to better illustrate exactly the error that I am getting.

I am following the tutorial thoroughly and as mentioned the Pi is fresh. I included the config.json file in the directory it's supposed to be in, and that folder looks just like in the tutorial.

Could this simply be due to using a more recent version of NOOBS as opposed to the 2.9.0 one? I haven't tried this workaround yet as I only have access to the Pi for a very short while once a week, so I tried looking similar problems up and trying quicker fixes, but none have worked so far. I will however have it with me today so I was wondering if anyone had some feedback so I don't miss out on another week.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `commentjson` is not compatible with python3 and the author has no plan to merge the relevant pull request. [See here](https://github.com/vaidik/commentjson/pull/15)

A workaround would be to modify the `setup.sh` script and use python2 instead.

Another sensible workaround is to modify the script and install [JSON_minify](https://pypi.org/project/JSON_minify/) instead. It seems like it provides similar functionality and same API interface (according to some folks over the pull request page).

Hope this helps.

Comment: It helps a lot! Thanks. Having said this I'm not familiar with what a 'pull request' is, and I'm also not entirely sure in what way to modify the setup.sh script in order to 'use python2 instead'. 
If you have a minute to go into more detail on it I'd appreciate it. Meanwhile, I'll be trying to do it on my own.

Comment: Pull request is the changes made by someone else on their end, usually bug fixes or feature improvements. Then the original author can merge their pull request to realize the new code. I have not seen the `setup.sh` but I believe it contains necessary snippet to install required libraries such as commentjson. You can go though it and modify the relevant lines and install the ones you need.

Comment: I just saw your own edit on JSON_minify. I was also going to try it after reading up on the link you gave me. Again, I don't understand that much of what I'm reading, but I'll give it a go.

Comment: Have fun and consider accepting this answer if it helps!

Comment: Hey @Rex Low, just to mention that I never did manage to fix the problem. I guess I'm just not tech savvy enough to do the changes you mentioned. I have since tried other tutorials running on different OS but always come down to the same problem with commentjson. 
Ah well, I'll keep trying to solve it.